# How to specify the line break character for CSVreader in java

Tags: java

- text qualifier : `"` (Double quotes)
- delimeter : `,`(comma)

file data :

1st row ->    cvhjczxjc,"dasdsad,sdasd
2nd row ->    "sree","test","vczxnvn"

While I am trying to read data all rows treated as single row due to non-terminated text qualifier.Actual second row is valid data.

Please guide us to solve this.

Code :

```
CSVReader csvReader = new CSVReader(new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream(f),Charset.forName("utf-8"))), ',','"');
while((csvDataLine = csvReader.readNext()) != null) {
            for (String str :csvDataLine){
                System.out.print(str+",");
            }
        System.out.println();
}
csvReader.close();
```

text file:[enter link description here](http://freetexthost.com/dte2nuxska)

Comment: Can you post the relevant parts of the sample file? I don't see a second row in your sample data.

Comment: Sure below is the url I have hosted my text file  in Open web  http://freetexthost.com/seisahnjev

Comment: Your CSV file is broken, you need to fix it (add a double quote to the end of the first line). CSV files can have newlines inside cells, so your CSV reader is correct to interpret your above data as a single row. You need to fix your data, not your parser.

Comment: I agree with that my csv file is broken.My concern is : In first row text qualifier not terminated properly but second row is properly data is there.While reading data using csv reader both rows are combining as single row.My requirement is text qualifier is not terminated properly then it should not combine both rows.Read data as individual rows.

Comment: Ask yourself: how would you differentiate your two lines above from a case where there was a newline inside a value? There is no way to differentiate the two. If you are fine with not supporting newlines inside values, then you can give each line to a CSV reader separately - most allow you to parse a String too, otherwise you can pass a StringReader with each individual line to your CSV parser in a loop.